# React Native - NavigationActions.navigate() not navigating from within redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation, redux-saga

I have two navigators one is stackNavigator and another is drawerNavigator. 
what I want to do is dispatch an action and login is successfull and redirect the user to drawer navigator. I have used react-navigation.
What I have done is I am dispatching the action login success in saga.
Using `NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'drawerStack' })` to dispatch the action.
The action dispatches successfully but it doesn't navigate to drawerNavigator as shown in the picture below. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

> saga.js

```
function* watchLoginRequest() {
  while (true) {
    const { state } = yield take(LOGIN_REQUEST);

    try {
      const payload = {
        state
      };
      const response = yield call(loginCall, payload);
      yield put(loginSuccess(response));
      yield setUser(response.user);
      yield put(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'drawerStack' }));
    } catch (err) {
      yield put(loginFailure(err.status));
    }
  }
}
```

> drawerNavigation.js

```
// drawer stack
const DrawerStack = DrawerNavigator({
  testComponent: { screen: TestComponent },
});

const DrawerNav = StackNavigator({
  drawerStack: { screen: DrawerStack }
}, {
  headerMode: 'float',
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'green' },
    title: 'Logged In to your app!',
    headerLeft: <Text onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}>Menu</Text>
  })
});

export default DrawerNav;
```

> loginNavigation.js

```
// login stack
const LoginStack = StackNavigator({

  startScreen: { screen: StartScreen },
  loginScreen: { screen: LoginScreen },
  personalInformation: { screen: PersonalInformation },
  vehicleInformation: { screen: VehicleInformation },
  availability: { screen: Availability },
  selectRegisteration: { screen: SelectRegisteration },
  serviceAddress: { screen: ServiceAddress },

}, {
  headerMode: 'none',
  transitionConfig: TransitionConfiguration

});


export default LoginStack;
```

> ReduxNavigation.js

```
class ReduxNavigation extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { dispatch, nav } = props;
    const navigation = ReactNavigation.addNavigationHelpers({
      dispatch,
      state: nav
    });
    this.state = {
      loggedInStatus: false,
      checkedSignIn: false
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    isSignedIn()
      .then(res => {
        if (res !== null) {
          this.setState({
            loggedInStatus: true,
            checkedSignIn: true
          });
        } else {
          console.log(res);
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  render() {
    return <LoginNavigation navigation={this.navigation} />;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ nav: state.nav });
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ReduxNavigation);
```

Comment: What are you expecting? To navigate to `TestComponent` or to show the drawer? To show the drawer you want `.navigate('DrawerOpen')`

Comment: Actually I am trying to navigate to TestComponent.

Comment: Its neither opening the drawer if I .navigate('DrawerOpen')

Comment: Where are you adding your drawer navigator to the navigation stack? You either aren't providing all the code, or you don't have your navigation stacks set up properly. `DrawerNavigator` needs to be added to the stack if you want to be able to navigate to any of it's paths

Comment: yup, I guess I need to configure and add navigation helpers properly so that both of my navigators are in sync with redux. Anyway thanks for your concern.

Comment: Personally, I found the navigation to be a bit confusing. I'd suggest starting with a basic setup without `redux` and getting an understanding of that. Then you can add `redux`. AFAIK, you can't modify the navigation stack on the fly, which is what it sounds like you might be trying to do. See https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/71

Comment: yes, I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

To navigate to `TestComponent` you want your `routeName` to be `testComponent`, not the drawer stack. You navigate to specific screens, not navigation components.

Comment: I have also tried to navigate to testComponent and some routeNames like selectRegisteration etc but it does the same, it does't get navigated to either of the screens